# time of an assembler operation

Tags: c++, assembly, time

Why can the same assembler operation (mul for example) in different parts of a program consume different amount of time?

P.S. I'm using C++ and disassembler.

Comment: Do you have a more specific example in mind, are you using x86 (_64?)? this is a little vague. This question is more about micro architecture than code. For example are you 'mul'ing two register's or two memory locations. Is it the first time you use the variable in a while causing  cache miss, as an opose to it being L(1-3) cache.

Comment: 64. In profiler I see "mulps %xmm11, %xmm5", for example. I guess it is data in registers.

Comment: correct if I am wrong but xmmXX are SSE registers it is performing that operation on as many as 4 floats or 2 double at a time

Comment: yes. Does it matter? I compare mulps with mulps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are all kinds reasons why the same kind of operation can have massively varying performance on modern processors.

- **Data Cache Misses**:
  If your operation accesses memory it might go to the cache at one location and generate a cache miss elsewhere. Cache misses can be in the order of a hundret cycles, while easy operations often execute in a few cycles, so this will make it much slower.
- **Pipeline Stalls**:
  Modern CPUs are typically pipelined, so an instruction (or more then one) can be scheduled each cycle, but they typically need more than one cycle till the result is available. Your operation might depend on the result of another operation, which isn't ready when the operation is scheduled, so the CPU has to wait till the operation generating the result has finished.
- **Instruction Cache Misses**:
  The instruction stream is also cached, so you might find a situation where for one location the cpu generates a cache miss each time it encounteres that location (unlikely for anything which will take a measurable amount of the runtime though, instruction caches aren't that small).
- **Branch Misprediction**:
  Another kind of pipeline stall. The CPU will try to predict which way a conditional jump will go and speculatively execute the code in that execution path. If it is wrong it has to discard the results from this speculative execution and start on the other path. This might show up on the first line of the other path in a profiler.
- **Resource Contention**: The operation might not depend a not avalible result, but the execution unit needed might still be occupied by another instruction (some instructions are not fully pipelined on all processors, or it might be because of some kind of Hyperthreading or Bulldozers shared FPU). Again the CPU might have to stall until the unit is free.
- **Page Faults**: Should be pretty obvious. Basically a Cache Miss on steroids. If the accessed memory has to be reloaded from disk it will cost hundreds of thousands of cycles
- **...**: The list goes on, however the mentioned points are the ones most likely to make an impact in my opionon.

Comment: don't confuse branch prediction and branch predication ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This question is very vague, but generally on a modern CPU you cannot expect operations to have a constant execution time, because a lot of factors can influence this, including but not limited to:

- Branch prediction failures
- Cache misses
- Pipelining
- ...

Comment: I love my AVR, where `mul` always takes the same number of cycles. Oh wait.. it has no `mul`.

Comment: @noah1989: don't try pic asm. It makes AVR look like amazing.

Comment: @noah1989 it really is, I need to switch

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking about exactly the same instruction applied to the same operands.

One possible cause that could have huge performance implications is whether the operands are readily available in the CPU cache or whether they have to be fetched from the main RAM.

This is just one example; there are many other potential causes. With modern CPUs it's generally very hard to figure out how many cycles a given instruction will require just by looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In profiler I see "mulps %xmm11, %xmm5", for example. I guess it is data in registers

xmmXX are SSE instructions. mulps is precision single, it depends whether or not you are comparing a SSE multiply against a normal scalar multiply. in which case it is understandable.

We really need more information for a better answer a chunk of asm and your profilers figures.

If it just this instruction that is slow? or a block of instructions, maybe it loading from unaligned memory, or you getting cache misses, pipeline hazards and a significant number of other possiblities.